# WPF BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync lock

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, synchronization

I would like to use a BackgroundWorker instance in WPF to perform some compute-bound operation. One can call RunWorkerAsync(...) method on one exact instance from different places. If it is called while IsBusy is true, InvalidOperationException is thrown. Can someone run worker between the check in the if(...) block and the corresponding call of RunWorkerAsync(1) in the following code?

```
    if(!_bgWorker.IsBusy) {
        _bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(1);
    }
```

If it happens is an InvalidOperationException thrown? Should I always write smth like the following when calling RunWorkerAsync(...)?

```
lock(_bgWorker) {
    if(!_bgWorker.IsBusy) {
        _bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(1);
    }
}
```

Is lock keyword a good technique to achive what I want?

Comment: You can have multiple `BackgroundWorker` objects, so just use a different one for each background job that you want to do. You certainly don't need to use `lock` with them.

Comment: @Sheridan Do you think I should use multiple BackgroundWorker objects to perfrom the only one operation which can be cancelled and restarted immediately or in the future? E. g., my operation will be called several times per second, and each call cancels the previous one.

Comment: If you only have one process to run in the background, then you'll only need one `BackgroundWorker`. Just ensure that you cancel the current work before starting the new work... I can't really see the problem here.

Comment: @Sheridan I will (1) check IsBusy and after that (2) call RunWorkerAsync. But what if RunWorkerAsync is called from somewhere else after (1) and before (2)?

Comment: Don't call it from anywhere else... just have a single entry point. Then you can be sure that it won't be running.

Comment: @Sheridan I suppose multiple entry points are necessary for restarting a BackgroundWorker object, arn't they? According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/915621/1561966 .

Comment: IMHO, you should not bother with `BackgroundWorker` for modern programs. Using `async`/`await`, optionally with `CancellationToken` addresses pretty much every need I've ever seen solved with `BackgroundWorker` previously.

Comment: @PeterDuniho So BackgroundWorker is not being used in professional development today? However if it was necessary to deal with BackgroundWorker, would you enclose RunWorkerAsync-calls in lock-statement?

Comment: @Hoborg: is it still used? I'm sure it is. It's a great feature of .NET & has served us well over the years. Like any useful tool, there'll always be people still using it even after something better comes along. But I do think `async`/`await` addresses the same kinds of problems `BackgroundWorker` was designed to solve, but in an even nicer way. As for locking, you should not have to do that: the point of BW is to create and start it from the one UI thread, so access to it should be naturally serialized in that way. But without a better code example, I can't say if you're misusing it here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for the explanation. About starting BW from the UI thred: I an going to start BW from either keyUp event handler or from OnRunWorkerCompleted event handler. Each new run will cancel the current one (if any).

Comment: @Hoborg: so as I suspected, you are only ever starting the BW from the UI thread (both of those events are always raised on the UI thread), so you don't need the additional lock. The UI thread itself serves as the synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @PeterDuniho But OnRunWorkerCompleted can raise AFTER IsBusy-check in keyUp event handler and BEFORE RunWorkerAsync in keyUp event handler, does not it? In that case it will run the BW right before its repeated kick off in the keyUp event handler (exception will follow).

Comment: @Hoborg: no, that's what I'm saying. _Nothing_ else can execute in the UI thread until your `KeyUp` event handler completes. Not even the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. There's no way for a single thread to race itself.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you. It seems that I have no StackOverflow-tools to appreciate your comments (just only mark an answer as correct if you like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the assumption that this code is executed on the UI thread, e.g. in the `KeyUp` event handler:

```
private void someControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if(!_bgWorker.IsBusy) {
        _bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(1);
    }
}
```

…and the assumption that you only ever start the worker from the UI thread, then we can be sure that the `IsBusy` property will not change between the time it's checked, and the call to `RunWorkerAsync()`.

To elaborate on this point…

There are two interesting scenarios that you want to avoid:

1. `IsBusy` is false, but then becomes true before you call
   RunWorkerAsync().
2. `IsBusy` is true, but then becomes false before
   this method returns

The first scenario is potentially more dangerous, because of course you can't start the worker if it's already started. But you know that first scenario can't happen, because a) you only start the worker from the UI thread, and nothing else can execute on the UI thread until this event handler returns, and b) assuming you are following the pattern shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635152/how-do-i-properly-cancel-and-restart-a-backgroundworker-process/915621#915621), the only other place you start the worker is in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler, which of course if the worker isn't running (i.e. `IsBusy` is false) could not be executed.

The second scenario is not dangerous per se (i.e. no exceptions), but of course could lead to the worker not being run when you want it to. But you know this scenario can't happen either, because the worker can only transition from `IsBusy` to `!IsBusy` after the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler has finished. Since that event handler is executed on the UI thread, just like this event handler, you know that it's not running while this event handler is running, and cannot start running until this event handler returns.

In other words, the UI thread where all of this code is required to execute acts as the necessary synchronization between the methods. A single thread cannot race with itself; everything that happens on that thread is required to happen one thing at a time. I.e. once a method starts executing on that thread, no other method can execute on that same thread until the first method has returned (or is called by the first method, of course, but that's not at issue here).

**Caveat:** in C# it's important to keep in mind that some types of methods are executed multiple times for a single call to that method. I.e. they *do* return before they are done. However, these are easy to notice: iterator methods even use the `return` keyword (i.e. as in `yield return`) to indicate this. The other place this happens is with `async` methods: at any `await` statement, the method can return (and usually does), allowing other methods to execute on the UI thread.

One other exception is if before the currently-running method returns, the `Application.DoEvents()` is called (i.e. either directly by the method, or indirectly by some method it calls), this can allow other window messages to be processed and hence some other event handler code to be called. This behavior, because it breaks the normal contract for UI thread execution, is why I advise that method *never* be used (it's never really needed anyway…it's only ever used as a hack to get around some other design issue in the code).

None of those exceptions apply here, but I want to make sure to mention them so that the general statements of fact in the answer are not misunderstood and applied too broadly.